# Find matching partial substring in python

Tags: python

I want to check if any element in noun matches any one of the elements in tables.

First element in nous in "devices". Clearly it matches with "projname:dataset.devices". If a match is found,
loop should break, else it should check whether second element in noun, which is "today" matches any element in the tables.

```
    tables = ["projname:dataset.devices","projname:dataset.attempts"]

    noun = [devices,today]
```

I tried it with "noun in tables", i got empty result. Is there any other method that I can try with?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Please add some context and the expected output.

Comment: Because `tables` is a `list`. A `list` is a container, you need to check the contents of the container, which is a single string in your example. `noun` is also a list, and you nee to check the *contents* of that list against the *contents* of another list.

Comment: does the noun list contains lists?

Comment: @LironLavi: Noun is a list which has two elements. I want to check whether any element in noun list matches partially with any element in devices list.

Comment: `noun` is a list, but are `devices` and `today` also Lists?

Comment: No devices and today are of type <type 'str'>.This is the output I get when I check the types of elements in noun. So I presume that they are strings.

Comment: "I want to check whether any element in noun list matches partially with any element in devices list" so when you say "devices list", that "devices" is not the same as the one in the `noun` list?

Comment: Apologies, it was a typo. "I want to check whether any element in noun list matches partially with any element in devices list" so when you say "tables list".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple use of `any(n in s for n in nouns for s in tables)` would suffice for a check.

If you actually want the matching item, you could write this quick function:

```
>>> def first_match(nouns, tables):
...     for n in nouns:
...         for t in tables:
...             if n in t:
...                 return t
...
>>> first_match(nouns,tables)
'projname:dataset.devices'
```

Comment: If any function returns true, I have to get the corresponding element in tables.

Answer (score 1):

**Task:**

1. 'Check if any element in noun matches any one of the elements in
   tables'
2. 'If any function returns true, I have to get the corresponding element in tables'

**Data:**

```
tables = ["projname:dataset.devices","projname:dataset.attempts"]
noun = ['devices','today']
```

**Generator expression**:

This only gives the first match, as per OP request.

```
try:
    print(next(t for n in noun for t in tables if n in t))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

**Output:**

```
   'projname:dataset.devices'
```

Comment: This is great if you want all matches, if you want to break as soon as you find something for efficiency reasons, though, this won't work.

Comment: this look like a more unnecessarily complicate solution of what is really needed.

Comment: @ade1e that is better, although it will trow a exception if nothing is found. Also, l think the order is reversed, you first should iterate over noun...

Comment: @ade1e by the way the OP describe it, it looks like he want to check the noun in order... Also, just for the record, there is another way to avoid the exception: `next(iterable,default)` which return the provided default value in case of a empty iterable.

Comment: @ade1e in the way that the OP describe it, it looks like he/she first want to check if there is any 'devices' first, and if there is none, then check for 'today', so for example in `tables=['today','devices']` the solution is 'devices'

Comment: @Copperfield, Op says in comments above 'If any function returns true, I have to get the corresponding element in tables'.  I think my solution does this but happy to learn if you can give me an example of how you would change it.  Please show me how you would modify my code. cheers

Comment: @ade1e the modification is simple, just change the order of iteration: `next(t for n in noun for t in tables if n in t)` (and is the same as the `any` function above)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your code, when you say `noun in tables` it means is a list (noun) INSIDE of another list (tables).  Thats not what we want to find out, rather you want to find each noun that exists inside of one of the elements of tables.  Try the following:

```
tables = ["projname:dataset.devices","projname:dataset.attempts"]

nouns = ["devices","today"]

for noun in nouns:
    for table in tables:
        if noun in table:
            print "Found", noun
            break
```

Comment: He wants a `break` after it finds something.

Comment: Thanks. Here "devices" in nouns matches "projname:dataset.devices" in tables. So the output should be "projname:dataset.devices". But "in" keyword does not do it. I tried with in already, which I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: The `in` keyword *does* do it, you are just using it incorrectly.

Comment: I tried with the above code, it returns empty result.

Comment: Consider to following issue: `noun = [devices,today]` doesnt that create a list of two elements, first being the devices variable and the second being the today variable.  What value do these variables have?  Are you mistakenly trying to write `noun = ['devices', 'today']`

Comment: I tried with type(noun) and type(tables) - both return <type 'list'>. I could not figure out why it does not work for me. However I will try to figure it out. Thanks very much.

Comment: `noun` and `tables` are both obviously lists - you are defining them as literals. But we don't know what `device` and `today` are. Try `type(noun[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple solution:

```
>>> tables = ["projname:dataset.devices","projname:dataset.attempts"]
>>> noun = ['devices','today']
>>> for x in noun:
        if any(x in s for s in tables):
            print('Found !')
            break


Found !
```

Comment: This does not print Found for any of the cases.

Comment: @user3447653, is `noun` a list of string or something else?

Comment: I just checked the type of elements in noun and tables. The result is <type 'str'>

Comment: So, how does this not work?, I tried it myself, and the output is from IDLE !

Comment: @IronFist looks like the OP want the element from tables that match a element from noun

Answer (score 0):

By your comment I assume the elements in the list aren't strings, **I** don't know any way of getting the var name on python, so this is my solution

```
    tables = ["projname:dataset.devices","projname:dataset.attempts"]

noun = {"devices": devices, "today": today}

for n in noun:
    for table in tables:
        if n in table:
            break
```